# Prove that if $f,g\in F[x]$ are non-constant polynomials, then $f(g)$ is a non-constant polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, function-and-relation-composition

For any polynomials $f$, $g$ $\in F[x]$ (where $F$ is a field), let $f(g)$ denote the polynomial obtained by substituting $g$ for the variable $x$ in $f$.
t, 
Suppose $f,g \in F[x]$ are **non-constant polynomials** (by non-constant, I mean they are of degree $> 0$. So, for example, $f(x) = 5$ is constant, while $g(x) = x^4 + 2x$ is not).  I need to prove that $f(g)$ is also a non-constant polynomial.

It seems like an extremely intuitive thing, and my thoughts are that it should be shown using a degree argument.

I.e., if $f,g$ are non-constant polynomials, then $deg(f)\geq 1$ and $deg(g) \geq 1$. So, I was thinking that I could show that then $deg(f(g))\geq 1$ as well, but I am not sure what the actual mechanics of showing this should be.

Could anybody please let me know how to go about proving this?  Thank you ahead of time for your time and patience!

Comment: Hello downvoter, rather than downvoting, how about suggesting ways I can make the question better? ;)

Comment: The North remembers.

Comment: This is not correct. Consider the polynomials $g(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = x^2+2x$  over the field with three elements. While $deg(f \circ g) = 4$, the polynomial is identically zero.

Comment: @HansEngler $f(g(x)) = x^4 + 2x^2$ is not constant, as it is of degree $4$. Perhaps the OP means something else when saying 'constant'. Constant as a function or as a polynomial?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff by constant I mean degree 0. Perhaps I ought to amend the question to better reflect this.

Comment: An interesting approach would be differentiating.

Comment: @BAI differentiating what?

Comment: Yes, as BAI suggests, take the derivative of f(g(x)), using the chain rule.  Since the derivative is non-zero the functiion is not constant.

Comment: @ALannister differentiating $f\circ g$, which could be shown, as $f$ and $g$ are non-constant, is not zero, which implies that $f\circ g$ is non-constant.

Comment: @BAI I don't think that argument works in positive characteristic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show that if $f$ is of degree $n$ and if $g$ is of degree $m$, then $f(g)$ is of degree $mn$. To this end, note that if $f = \lambda X^n + \cdots$ and if $g = \mu X^m+\cdots$ then the unique term of degree $mn$ in $f(g)$ is $\lambda \mu^m X^{mn}$, and this is nonzero since $\lambda\mu^m\neq 0$.

Comment: the North might remember, but I always pay my debts.